# R place quotes around all words except a certain one

Tags: regex, r, replace, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to use the `gsub` function to place single quotations around all words except in the case the word "one". I have tried the following but it is not working as I expected it would.

```
text <- "one two three four five one six one seven one eight nine ten one"
gsub("(?<!one)([a-zA-Z]+)", "'\\1'", text)
```

The output should be:

```
one 'two' 'three' 'four' 'five' one 'six' one 'seven' one 'eight' 'nine' 'ten' one
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems ironic that the one is "the one"

Answer (score 2):

For starters, `(?<!...)` is **PCRE** in which the `perl = TRUE` parameter needs to be enabled.

The trick is to use lookahead here instead of lookbehind and add [**word boundaries**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary) to force the regular expression engine to match whole words. Also, you broadly stated **words**; in my vocabulary this could mean any kind of word so I am going to use the Unicode property [`\pL`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), which matches any kind of letter from any language, if this matches more than expected you can simply change it back to `[a-zA-Z]` or use the POSIX named class `[[:alpha:]]` instead.

```
gsub("(?i)\\b(?!one)(\\pL+)\\b", "'\\1'", text, perl=T)
# [1] "one 'two' 'three' 'four' 'five' one 'six' one 'seven' one 'eight' 'nine' 'ten' one"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below the PCRE regex

```
> gsub('\\bone\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|([A-Za-z]+)', "'\\1'", text, perl=TRUE)
[1] "one 'two' 'three' 'four' 'five' one 'six' one 'seven' one 'eight' 'nine' 'ten' one"
```

`\\bone\\b` matches the text `one` and the following `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the match to skip and then fail. Now it uses the pattern which was on the right side of `|` operator to select characters from the remaining string (ie, except the skipped part)

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lK9zP7/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it in steps.  First by quoting every word and then removing the quotes from the word you don't want quoted.  It will probably solve what you need but may need some additional fine tuning for punctuation.

```
test <- paste0("'", text, "'")
test <- gsub(" ", "' '", test)
test <- gsub("'one'", "one", test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an odd thing to use regular expressions for. If you have more complicated expressions, perhaps something like this would work (and would be more readable).

```
# for piping and equals() and not()
library(magrittr)

#helper function
partialswap <- function(x, criteria, transform) {
    idx<-criteria(x)
    x[idx]<-transform(x[idx])
    x
}
not_equals <- function(x) . %>% equals(x) %>% not
is_not_in <- function(x) . %>% is_in(x) %>% not

text <- "one two three four five one six one seven one eight nine ten one"
strsplit(text, " ")[[1]] %>% 
    partialswap(not_equals("one"), shQuote) %>% 
    paste(collapse=" ")
# [1] "one 'two' 'three' 'four' 'five' one 'six' one 'seven' one 'eight' 'nine' 'ten' one"
```

Or if you wanted to leave off "one" and "three"

```
strsplit(text, " ")[[1]] %>% 
    partialswap(is_not_in(c("one","three")), shQuote) %>% 
    paste(collapse=" ")
# [1] "one 'two' three 'four' 'five' one 'six' one 'seven' one 'eight' 'nine' 'ten' one"
```

Comment: The regex seems about as cryptic and probably faster.

Comment: Certainly this won't be faster. But what if you wanted to escape neither "one" nor "three"? Then the regular expression would start to get much uglier.